# Waiting for an event to resolve before ending a C# task

Tags: c#, events

Is there a way to have a task wait until some sort of flag in the Task context itself is triggered? Take for example this code:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public event Action SomeEvent;

    public void triggerEventIn1Sec()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            SomeEvent.Invoke();
        });
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task mtask1 = SomeTask();
        mtask1.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Task1 completed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Task SomeTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            var c = new SomeClass();
            c.SomeEvent += () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some Event invoked");
            };
            c.triggerEventIn1Sec();
        });
    }
}
```

The Task returned from the SomeTask() function is waited on in the Main function. The Wait is completed before the event in the SomeTask Task is triggered.

Is there someway to specify in this Task function

```
   return Task.Run(() => {
        var c = new SomeClass();
        c.SomeEvent += () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Some Event invoked");
        };
        c.triggerEventIn1Sec();
    });
```

To wait until the event has been triggered before "completing the task"?

Comment: Why are you using events in the first place when you're using a Task based program?  Just have `triggerEventIn1Sec` return a `Task` that will be completed after 1 second, rather than firing an event in 1 second.

Comment: @Servy I want to have multiple tasks doing different unrelated things. any of these asynchronous tasks can be pushing a message to a messagebroker and waiting for a response, the response is an event that needs and event handler to receive. The Task can't be complete until we get a response from the message broker or an exception is thrown